# Ontology linking classes for online store

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, ontology

I'm trying to create ontology for store with Protege 4.3. Everything goes well, but I stuck on something.

I have two classes - Products and Stores. Currently they have object property hasProduct, which has domain Stores and range Products. Let's say that store "Tempo Sport Shop" hasProduct "Brown slippers". But there is a store named "Sport Depot" which has the same product but with different price.

I'm curious how can I put a different price for this product in different stores? I want those Brown Slippers to be 33.00$ in Sport Depot and the exactly same product to cost 41.00$ in Tempo Sport Shop.

Here's the ontology:

```
@prefix : <http://www.semanticweb.org/yuriy/ontologies/2014/0/untitled-ontology-23#> .

<http://www.semanticweb.org/yuriy/ontologies/2014/0/untitled-ontology-23> rdf:type owl:Ontology .


:hasBrand rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;

 rdfs:range :Brands ;

 rdfs:domain :Products .


:hasProduct rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;

  rdfs:range :Products ;

  rdfs:domain :Stores .

:Brands rdf:type owl:Class .

:Products rdf:type owl:Class .

:Stores rdf:type owl:Class .


:Adidas rdf:type :Brands ,
  owl:NamedIndividual .

:Fluffy_Slippers rdf:type :Products ,
  owl:NamedIndividual ;

  :hasBrand :Nike .

:Nike rdf:type :Brands ,
  owl:NamedIndividual .

:Sport_Depot rdf:type :Stores ,
  owl:NamedIndividual ;

  :hasProduct :Fluffy_Slippers .

:Tempo_Sport rdf:type :Stores ,
  owl:NamedIndividual ;

  :hasProduct :Fluffy_Slippers .
```

Comment: You could introduce a class *Offer* that connects a product with a store and a price.

Comment: Can you please be more specific. Something like a relation table in SQL databases? Can you give a simple example please :)

Comment: @user3156345 ORMapper's comment, and Michael's answers are pointing you in the right direction.  The relationship you're concerned with with is 3-place relation:  "A **Store** sells a **Product** for some **Price**."  Reading [Defining N-ary Relations on the Semantic Web](http://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-n-aryRelations/) might help you out here. The main idea is that you'll need some third object that somehow connects to all three things (viz., the store, the product, and the price).

Answer (score 2):

I'd do something like:

```
:Sport_Depot :sells [ :product :Fluffy_Slippers; 
                      :price "33.00"; 
                      :price_unit "USD" ].
```

Comment: This is Annotation right? What would the query for getting all prices from different stores look like in your example? :)

Comment: select distinct ?store ?price where { ?store :sells ?item . ?item :price ?price }

Comment: This is not an annotation.  This is one way of modeling n-ary relations.